# Watir-webdriver not grabbing the specified divs, and not sure why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

So this is the code for the controller, that I'm trying to use.

```
class ScraperController < ApplicationController

  def getinformation
      require 'watir-webdriver'
      require 'phantomjs'

      @browser = Watir::Browser.new:phantomjs
      @browser.goto "http://reddit.com"
      @divs = @browser.divs(class: "title may-blank ")

  end

end
```

On the view page, I have <%= @divs.length %> and it's outputting 0.  When I type <%= browser.title %> on the view page it gives me "reddit: the front page of the internet", so I know I'm getting something from the webpage.

I found the div class "title may-blank " by inspecting the titles of some of the posts on the home page, and I have tried using the div class "title may-blank " and "title may-blank".  One with the space at the end, how it's shown when it's inspected on the reddit page and one without the space at the end.  Both give me nothing though.

Comment: You should switch to "Watir" instead of "Watir-Webdriver". The Watir-Webdriver codebase is deprecated. It's updates now occur in Watir.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  Will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to locate:

```
<a class="title may-blank outbound" data-event-action="title" href="https://i.redd.it/kxtpiskh9mez.jpg" tabindex="1" data-href-url="https://i.redd.it/kxtpiskh9mez.jpg" data-outbound-url="https://out.reddit.com/t3_6si8wj?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fkxtpiskh9mez.jpg&amp;token=AQAAKQiLWXNK30ZkH9-TplVYPCVEIJwNWgqFZCdFuOc3O5l1c7M1&amp;app_name=reddit.com" data-outbound-expiration="1502283817000" rel="">Fries</a>
```

The problem is the element is an `a` rather than a `div`. You need to do at least:

```
@browser.links(class: "title may-blank ")
```

While this will return results, it might not be everything you expect. Supporting multiple classes in a `String` is also being deprecated in Watir.

I think you actually want just:

```
@browser.links(class: "title")
```

If you do want both classes, use:

```
@browser.links(class: ["title", "may-blank"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I tried looking through the Watir documentation before to try and solve my problem before posting on stackoverflow, but couldn't seem to find my answer there.  Did I just need to look harder or is there a good tutorial for Watir that you know of?

Comment: You could try my book, [Watirways](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-locating-an-element---basics). It's only partially written and a bit dated, but it's a starting point.